# Godot engine have a bug or unexpected feature?

Tags: variables, godot

I have some sort of bug, but I can't understand why it works so.
Press + mean shift gear up, - shift gear down. 0-off, 1,2,3 - shifts.
thrust limit by 0 shift - 0, 1-st shift - 200, 2-nd shift - 400, 3-rd shift = 600.

Code below work proper if acceleration_time=0.5 or 1 or 1.95 or 2.1 or 3.3
Thrust don't work if acceleration_time=2 or 3 or 4....
Thrust just stay 0 and that's all.
I don't understand why?!

```
extends Node2D

var shift=0
var thrust=0
var acceleration_time=1 #in seconds between shifts limits
var thrust_limits=[0,200,400,600] #shift0, shift1, shift2, shift3

func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("throttleUP"):
        if shift<3:
            shift+=1
            
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("throttleDown"):
        if shift>0:
            shift-=1
    
    if thrust<thrust_limits[shift]:
        thrust+=200*delta*(1/acceleration_time)
    if thrust>thrust_limits[shift]:
        thrust-=200*delta*(1/acceleration_time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running against an integer division.

You are defining `acceleration_time` as `1` which is an `int` (unlike `1.0` which is a `float`). And you are dividing `1/acceleration_time`, which would be `int` divided by `int`… and that gives you an `int`.

Thus, when you have `acceleration_time = 2`, you are doing `1/2` and that is `0`, which nullifies the increment you apply to `thrust`.

---

You can use literals with a decimal point for `float`: `1.0/acceleration_time` or you can type your variables:

```
var acceleration_time:float = 1
```

Or:

```
var acceleration_time:float = 1.0
```

Or:

```
var acceleration_time := 1.0
```

Which types the variable with the type of what you used to initialize it.

Yes, GDScript has types. Use them. *These are not just hints. I repeat: these are not just hints.*

Comment: Sorry for such a noob question! I got it! Thanks for help!!! )))